# Solr transformer Peformance : [child] vs [subquery]

Tags: solr, lucene

While reading through the solr [docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_subquery_), it seems **[subquery] is an improvement over [child]**. It seems better wrt. the capabilities (sorting of nested documents, etc).

But is it better in terms of performance as well ?

1 of the requirements of my current project is to sort the child documents for every parent. *[child]* doesnt seem to have that support. *[subquery]* has it, but it seems to be more expensive.

As per my understanding, *[child]* only gets executed within the boundaries of the child docs for a given parent. Whereas *[subquery]* gets executed across the index.
Please help in validating the hypothesies. Can i use the *[subquery]* transformer as efficiently as the *[child]* transfromer itself.

Comment: Bump.............

Comment: were you able to compare the performance of both queries? I have the same question as you